# Is there a way to check a file encoding using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding, encode, ansi

Here's my case: I'm working with a very big project that contains lots of files. Some of these files are encoded in UTF-8, other in ANSI. We need to convert all the files to UTF-8, because we decided this will be the default in our next projects.
This is a big concern because we're Brazilian and we have common words using characters like á, ç, ê, ü, etc. So having multiple files in multiple charset-encodes generated a serious issue.

Anyway, I've come to this JS file that converts ANSI files to UTF-8, copying them to another folder and preserving the originals:

```
var indir = "in";
var outdir = "out";
function ansiToUtf8(fin, fout) {
    var ansi = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream");
    ansi.Open();
    ansi.Charset = "x-ansi";
    ansi.LoadFromFile(fin);
    var utf8 = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream");
    utf8.Open();
    utf8.Charset = "UTF-8";
    utf8.WriteText(ansi.ReadText());
    utf8.SaveToFile(fout, 2 /*adSaveCreateOverWrite*/);
    ansi.Close();
    utf8.Close();
}
var fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var folder = fso.GetFolder(indir);
var fc = new Enumerator(folder.files);
for (; !fc.atEnd(); fc.moveNext()) {
    var file = fc.item();
    ansiToUtf8(indir+"\\"+file.name, outdir+"\\"+file.name);
}
```

which I run using this in command line

> cscript /Nologo ansi2utf8.js

The problem is that this script runs through all the files, even the ones that are already in UTF-8, and this results in breaking my special characters. So I need to check if the file encoding is already UTF-8, and run my code only if it is ANSI.
How can I do that?

Also, my script is running only through the 'in' folder. I'm still thinking in a easy way to make it go inside folders that are in this folder and run there too.

Comment: What environment are you doing this on?  My first thought is that JS is probably not the right tool for the job here.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 and I code in PHP/JavaScript. I don't know if this can be reproduced using another programming language, but it's not the case, because I probably won't know how to do it.

Comment: If you do PHP, possibly consider the mbstring library: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your UTF-8 files have a byte order mark? In that case you could simply check the value of the first 3 bytes to determine if the files are UTF-8 or not. Otherwise the standard method is to check if the file is legal UTF-8 all the way through, if so it is most likely supposed to be read as UTF-8.